# MVC4: Is it possible with one Ajax call to controller from view to get back partial view as html and Json format data ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC4: is it possible with one Ajax call to controller action from script on razor view to get back partial view as html and Json format data ?
Now I have two functions that make two trips to controller to two diff actions, each action calls same stored procedure to get data from db. I would like to combine it into one call.

VIEW scripts section:

```
function getPartialViewHtml(){      
   var val1=1;

   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'Home/GetPartialViewHtml',
       data: { parm1 : val1 },
       success:  function(htmlResult){
          $('#divShowPartial').html(data);
          getJsonResult(val1);
       }
   });
}

function getJsonResult(val1)
{
   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'Home/GetJsonResult',
       data: { parm1 : val1 },
       success:  function(jsonResult){
          $('#txtShowJsonData1').val(data.text1);  
          $('#txtShowJsonData2').val(data.text2);            
       }
   });
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public PartialViewResult GetPartialViewHtml(int parm1)
{
   PartialViewModel model = new PartialViewModel(parm1);  // calls MyOtherModel model= new MyOtherModel (parm1); 
   return PartialView("MyPartialView", model);
}

public ActionResult GetJsonResult(intparm1)
{
   MyOtherModel model= new MyOtherModel (parm1); 
   return Json(model);  
}
```

MODELS

```
class PartialViewModel 
{
   public MyModel mm {get; set;}

   public string otherData {get; set;}
   ........
}

class MyModel
{
   public int id {get; set;}
   public string text1 {get; set;}
   public string text2 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You could add or remove the html you need changed on return and contain it inside a div fx?

Comment: Since both methods return the same model (just in a different format), why not just set the value of `$('#txtShowJsonData1')` based on the value of an element returned in the partial view e.g. `$('#txtShowJsonData1').val($('#text1').val());` where `#text1` is the id of the relevant element returned in the partial

Comment: Good suggestion Stephen. But I have several diff partial views, I will have to change id-s in all of them, it's doable, but, there will be more diff partial views, and somebody else may be coding those without knowing to use particular control id-s. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, it is the nature of your return types.

Notice: `PartialViewResult` and `ActionResult`. You could switch ActionResult for `JsonResult` since that makes more sense in your code.

You could fire two synchronous AJAX calls instead of chaining their callbacks.

```
function getPartialViewHtml() {      
   var val1 = 1;
   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'Home/GetPartialViewHtml',
       data: { parm1 : val1 },
       async: false,
       success:  function(htmlResult){
          $('#divShowPartial').html(data);
       }
   });
   $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: 'Home/GetJsonResult',
       data: { parm1 : val1 },
       async: false,
       success:  function(jsonResult){
          $('#txtShowJsonData1').val(data.text1);  
          $('#txtShowJsonData2').val(data.text2);            
       }
   });
}
```

That saves your from declaring two separate functions.